# A question regarding Google patent search

Tags: search, patent-search, google-patents

This [blog says](https://www.greyb.com/blog/google-patents-search-guide/):

> ‘AJD’, ‘AJDx’, ‘ADJ/x’, ‘xw’ – These are also proximity operators which are the same as NEAR, but matches must be in the same order.

However, when I searched in [Google patent site](https://patents.google.com/) with the following keywords:

> TI=("smart" ADJ/2 "ring")

The result does not match with what the site claimed. I want all the results where title must contains both "smart" and "ring" orderly within range 2 words. What should be the correct query and why?

Saying unexpected results because it also included a title like: ***"Smart-home device installation guidance"***

Comment: I've tried your example and can confirm the feature doesn't work. All I can say is that Google Patents, while convenient, isn't the best site for free patent searching. I prefer Lens. https://www.lens.org/lens/

Comment: What would be the search structure for what I want in lens.org? @EricS

Comment: Not an expert, but the documentation is pretty good. https://support.lens.org/knowledge-base/proximity-search/

Comment: @EricS thanks a lot. I will check it soon.

Comment: Not a problem. Lens might not do exactly what you are looking for, but I find it generally more robust than Google Patents.